# If $P(X = 3) = 1$ and $P(Y = 4) = 1$ then is it true that $P(X/Y = 3/4) = 1$. Is independence necessary?

Tags: probability

Seems like a very simple and intuitive result but I'm having trouble showing it formally. Thanks for your help and patience.

> If $P(X = 3) = 1$ and $P(Y = 4) = 1$ then $P(X/Y = 3/4) = 1$
>
> If this is true, do $X$ and $Y$ need to be independent?

**My attempt**

I think it is true. I use independence which I don't think is necessary...

If $P(A) = 1$ and $P(B) = 1$ then the probability of both events occuring $P(AB) = 1$.

So we have $P(X = 3, Y = 4) = 1$.

Let's create a new event $W = X/Y$

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent $P(W) = P(X/Y) = P(X)P(1/Y)$

I think it's acceptable to say that $Y=4$ is equivalent to $1/Y = 1/4$

Therefore the conclusion follows.

Thanks.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think we can argue if $P(X) = 1$ then it is independent of *everything*.  $P(X) = 1$ if $Z$ occurs, and $P(X) = 1$ if $Z$ doesn't occur.  Isn't that independence?  Now if $P(W) = 0$ then ... well I don't know what $P(X|Z)$ so I don't know if an event can/can not/must/must not be dependent on an impossible event.  But otherwise, I'd say an inevetible event is independent of everything else.

Comment: You could say $X = 3\& Y = 4\implies \frac XY = \frac 34$ so $P(\frac XY = \frac 34) \ge P(X=3\&Y=4) = 1$

Comment: @fleablood yes that seems to make sense. I suppose if a RV equals one value with probability $1$ it is a constant RV and all constant RVs are independent of everything... I know the answer is intuitive but I'm trying to see a very pedantic formal approach. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not given independence; thus write the joint probabilities as P(X=0,Y=0) = p00. P(X=0,Y=4) = p04
P(X=3,Y=0) = p30 and P(X=3,Y=4) = p34.  Note that X = 0
Represents X not equal to 3, for example.

We now interpret the given conditions as marginal probabilities and have that p00 + p04 = P(X = 0) = 0 because P(X =1) = 1.
All probabilities are non-negative so this means that p00=p04=0.
Similarly, the equation p00 + p30 = P(Y = 0) = 0 implies p30=0.

Three of the probabilities are zero and the sum of the four probabilities must be 1.  It follows that the joint probability p34 = 1.  The fact that P(X = 3, Y = 4) =1 is equivalent to
P(X/Y = 3/4) and we did not need independence.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you elaborate more on the last sentence... it is intuitive but I don't know the rules very well of doing operations on the probability of events. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Look up functions of random variables and consider the function f(x,y) = x/y, y not 0. We DEFINE the probabilities of the composite f(X,Y) based on the probabilities of the RVs X and Y. For this case, f(X,Y) = 3/4 only when X=3 and Y=4. The probability of that is p34 = 1.